# natural cubic spline regression with R

Tags: r, regression, lm, spline, cubic-spline

I seem to have a problem with the `splines::ns()` function in R.

I created a simple dummy problem

```
dat <- data.frame(t <- seq(0, 6, .01),
                  x <- rnorm(length(t), sd = 1),
                  y <- 5 + t - x^2 + rnorm(length(t), sd = .33))

lm(y ~ t + I(x^2), data = dat)

library(splines)
lm(y ~ t + ns(x, knots = c(0), Boundary.knots = c(-3, 3)), data = dat)
```

While the first model works fine, the second one fails to identify the intercept correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would suggest defining columns within the data.frame using `=` instead of `<-`. `names(df)` will reveal that your data.frame currently has complex column names.

Comment: I am not surprised the second model estimates an intercept different from 5, since the model used to fit the data is different from the true data generating model.

Comment: I would suggest migrating this question to crossvalidated -- this is more of a statistical issue than an R issue.

Answer (score 5):

**There is nothing wrong, because you are not fitting exactly the same model, and they are not even equivalent.**

To explain the different result you see, it is sufficient to use a simpler example with a single covariate `x`. We generate data from a quadratic polynomial: `5 + x + x^2`, then fit several models.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(500, mean = 1)  ## `x` with non-zero mean
y <- 5 + x + x * x + rnorm(500, sd = 0.5)
library(splines)

fit1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
#(Intercept)            x       I(x^2)  
#      4.992        1.032        0.980  

fit2 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = 2))
#(Intercept)  poly(x, degree = 2)1  poly(x, degree = 2)2  
#      7.961                70.198                28.720

fit3 <- lm(y ~ bs(x, degree = 2, df = 2))
#(Intercept)  bs(x, degree = 2, df = 2)1   bs(x, degree = 2, df = 2)2  
#      6.583                      -8.337                       20.650  

fit4 <- lm(y ~ ns(x, df = 2))
#(Intercept)  ns(x, df = 2)1  ns(x, df = 2)2  
#      5.523          10.737          21.265
```

The first 3 models are not the same, in terms of parameterization, but they are equivalent: they are all fitting a quadratic polynomial with 3 degree of freedom. To see their equivalence, we check their fitted values:

```
sum(abs(fit1$fitted - fit2$fitted))
# [1] 1.54543e-13

sum(abs(fit1$fitted - fit3$fitted))
# [1] 2.691181e-13
```

To see the difference in parameterization, we look at the design matrix:

```
X1 <- model.matrix(~ x + I(x^2))
X2 <- model.matrix(~ poly(x, degree = 2))
X3 <- model.matrix(~ bs(x, degree = 2, df = 2))

par(mfrow = c(3,3), oma = rep.int(1,4), mar = c(4, 4, 0, 0))

plot(x, X1[, 1], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X1[, 2], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X1[, 3], cex = 0.2)

plot(x, X2[, 1], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X2[, 2], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X2[, 3], cex = 0.2)

plot(x, X3[, 1], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X3[, 2], cex = 0.2)
plot(x, X3[, 3], cex = 0.2)
```

[image]

Since the design matrix are not the same (either in shapes or in scales), you will not end up with the same set of coefficients. In case you are surprised, let's try a even simpler example:

```
x1 <- x - mean(x)
test <- lm(y ~ x1 + I(x1^2))
#(Intercept)           x1      I(x1^2)  
#      7.003        2.991        0.980 

sum(abs(fit1$fitted - test$fitted))
# [1] 1.24345e-13
```

Here, I have just taken some simple transform for `x`, then the result is different (but still equivalent).

The 4th model `fit4`, is fitting a cubic polynomial with 3 degree of freedom, so it is not equivalent to all previous models. We can check fitted values:

```
sum(abs(fit1$fitted - fit4$fitted))
# [1] 39.36563
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring ns() completely you are missing two things:

1) The comment above explaining how to define a dataframe:

```
t <- seq(0, 6, .01)
x <- rnorm(length(t), sd = 1)
y <- 5 + t - x^2 + rnorm(length(t), sd = .33)
df <- data.frame(t, x, y)       
rm(t, x, y)
```

2) The way you are calling your models:

```
lm(y ~ t + I(t^2), data=df)
lm(y ~ splines::ns(t, knots = c(0), Boundary.knots = c(-3, 3)), data=df)
```

The first model does not properly identify what you think it does.